# Seforim/Books on Klalei Horo'oh

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

Can anyone recommend a good sefer explaining Klalei Horo'oh - how a Rov reaches a psak, being machria between different acharonim etc?

Comment: https://www.israelbookshop.com/the-making-of-a-halachic-decision-by-rabbi-moshe-walter.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sefer Yad Malachi is an extremely important work ,and the Shach's(Yoreh Deah 242) klalim on psak. There is also an amazing Kuntres that can be found in the back of volume 1 of Sheaarim Metzuyanim B'halacha on shas that discusses seder toras halimmud, and toras horaah and minhagim. Alot of great mareh mekomos and interesting opinions on the subject(see number 8 about the Birkei Yosef's opinion of paskining from seforim). For Chacham Ovadia's understanding of derech  psak see the beginning of the first volume .

[image]

Comment: It's important to remember that all these rules are just guidelines. There is no substitute to learning how to paskin from an actual person who knows how.

Comment: @doubleaa that is true, but there are rules to that as well ,I prefer not to write anything in a public forum which may get misconstrued, so will leave it at that